# Section Index Titles Cover UITableViewCell View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview, ios-autolayout

I am trying to add a stack view to my UITableViewCell programmatically.

The section index titles obstruct the view as such.

[image]

Here is the code I am using to embed the stack view in the UITableViewCell.

```
self.addSubview(mainStack)
mainStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: self.TOP_PADDING).isActive = true
mainStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -self.BOTTOM_PADDING).isActive = true
mainStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: self.SIDE_PADDING).isActive = true
mainStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

How can I fix the view obstruction without relying on a fixed constant (i.e. some fixed padding)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
mainStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

To

```
mainStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: In addition to the constraints, you should be adding your cell's subviews to the `contentView`, not directly to the cell itself.

Comment: @dan Thank you for your comment. Intuitively that makes sense (given the name "contentView"), but do you have a source for that? I have not experienced any issues adding to the cell itself except for this one, in particular.

Comment: @JoshWolff - take a look at this page of Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell -- the images clearly demonstrate why elements should be added to the `contentView` and not to the cell itself.

Comment: @DonMag ah, got it. Thank you!